# On Lyapunov function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

Given the ODE system $x'=y, y'=-h(y)g(x)$ where $h,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous and $h(y)>0$ and $x.g(x)>0$, for all $x\neq0$ Determine sufficient condition on the existence of the solution of the ODE. Consider $V(x,y)=\int^y_0\frac{s}{h(s)}ds+\int^x_0g(s)ds$ the Lyapunov function.

My attempt: I've shown that $V'=0$, however, I don't know how to show the uniform convergence to infinity.

Comment: What do you mean by existence of the solution to the ODE? The assumptions of continuity on $g$ and $h$ are sufficient to give you existence in a space-time neighbourhood of any initial point $((x_0, y_0), t_0)$. Do you mean global existence? What about periodic orbits (such as in the case $h \equiv 1$, $g(x) = x$)?

Comment: Yes, it's about the global existence. My difficult is to prove that $V(x,y)\rightarrow\infty$, as $\|(x,y)\|\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: You are to find **sufficient conditions**. A sufficient condition for the global existence (for positive times) of a solution is that $V(x,y)\to\infty$ as $\lVert(x,y)\rVert\to\infty$. So, what are the simplest (in your case) sufficient conditions for that sufficient condition to be satisfied?  Do you know improper integrals?

Comment: Yes, I know about improper integrals, however I don't know to use the hypothesis to obtain thar $V(x,y)\rightarrow\infty$. Why is necessary $h(y)>0$ and $x.g(x)>0$?

Comment: Assume that $\int_0^\infty g(s) \, ds = \infty$, $\int_{-\infty}^0 g(s) \, ds = - \infty$, $\int_0^\infty \frac{s}{h(s)} ds = \infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{s}{h(s)} ds = -\infty$.